# django form errorlist "This field is required" with extra field and upload file

Tags: javascript, html, django, python-3.x

I have problems to get data back to my django view with a form. I have a model form with a filefield ("file"), and added an extra charfield ("paths"). My initial view allow to get the uploaded file, but when I tried to integrate the other charfield, it doesn't work, and I always get the error bellow (at the end):

I should precise that I m working with jquery.uploadfile and I use Drag and Drop to set the "file" field. At the beginning the form wasn't necessary in the template, it should be created automatically with the jquery.uploadfile library I think.

I think I already read all the related answers  in other posts, can't find a solution :)

this is my form :

```py
class MonsterForm(forms.ModelForm):

    paths = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Monster
        fields = ('file','paths',)
```

this is my post function view that works fine for the upload, where I got the error:

```py
def post(self, request):    
        form = MonsterForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        print(form.errors)
        if form.is_valid():

            ''' trying to get the field value here '''
            print("post : ",self.request.POST.get('paths'))

            temp_file = form.save(commit=False)
            ''' some code '''
            temp_file.save()
            # data.result sent back to template :
            data = {'is_valid': True, 'name': temp_file.title, 'url': temp_file.get_absolute_url()}
            ''' just for tests '''
        else:
            data = {'is_valid': False}
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

And this is my template :

```html
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <input type="text" name="paths" id="id_paths" value="test"/>
    <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="file" multiple style="display: none; " data-url="{% url 'upload' %}" data-form-data='{"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'/>

</form>
```

and the error :

```html
<ul class="errorlist"><li>paths<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

I added the  and the text input but still not working, any idea ?
thx

Comment: `jquery.uploadfile` will only submit the file, not the other input field.

Comment: For which field error is coming ?

Comment: you need to customise a little bit the javascript for jquery upload-file (are you using [this](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php#doc)?), for example add an `onSubmit()` handler that adds the `paths` data to the `FormData` that is submitted.

Comment: -Ok ! I get it I m not submitting the text input field - Error is for the Charfield - Yes I m using this jquery file, I will look at onSubmit right now - thx all !